# Azure VM - site isn't reachable externally

Tags: azure, dns, cloud, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure and got confused with my setting.
I've created a VM, and I can see I have the below:
[image]

Both are pointing to the same app with the same IP.

I have connected to the machine using RDP, set the IIS correctly and deployed my WebAPI. **When tested locally all seems to be fine**.
However, the site isn't reachable externally, neither with the CloudApp domain (nmsw10services.cloudapp.net) nor my own domain which is pointing to the same IP.

[image]

[image]

Can someone please point what I'm doing wrong in here?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need add endpoints for your web app.**

By default, when you create a classic VM, it will create an endpoint for RDP (port 3389). You also need add your endpoints according to your app.

[image]

More information about endpoints please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints#create-an-endpoint).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick and now everything is fine.
Much appreciated!